# Warnings on `body-cell-<column>` attribute and props

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, quasar

In a Vue 3, TypeScript, and Quasar project, I have a component with this table:

```
        <q-table
            @row-click="rowClick"
            title="Runners"
            :rows="rows"
            :columns="columns"
            :rows-per-page="rowsPerPage"
            row-key="slug"
            table-header-style="font-size: 2em;"
            selection="single"
            @selection="selectRunner"
            v-model:selected="selectedRow"
        >
          <template v-slot:body-cell-registration="props">
            <q-td :props="props">
              <template v-if="props.row.registration === 'U'">
                {{ props.value }}
                (<a href="#" @click="handleRegisterClick(props.row.slug); $event.stopPropagation()">
                Register
              </a>)
              </template>
              <template v-else-if="props.row.registration === 'R'">
                {{ props.value }}
                (<a href="#" @click="handleDeregisterClick(props.row.slug); $event.stopPropagation()">
                Deregister
              </a>)
              </template>
              <template v-else>
                {{ props.value }}
              </template>
            </q-td>
          </template>
        </q-table>
```

This works, it shows the correct value and 'Register' and 'Deregister' links as appropriate, and it all works and updates reactively as intended.

However, my editors show a warning for `v-slot:body-cell-registration`, saying that `body-cell-registration` is an 'unrecognised slot name'. Also, the `row` part of `props.row.registration` gets a 'Unresolved variable row'.

The type of the rows for the `q-table` this is a part of is imported from another file:

```
export interface RunnerRow {
    slug: string;
    status: string;
    status_display: string;
    registration: string;
    registration_display: string;
    node_slug: string;
    node_type: string;
    node_type_display: string;
    hostname: string;
    username: string;
}
```

And the columns are defined as:

```
const columns = [
  {name: 'slug', label: 'Slug', field: 'slug', sortable: true},
  {name: 'status', label: 'Status', field: 'status_display'},
  {name: 'registration', label: 'Registration', field: 'registration_display'},
  {name: 'node_type', label: 'Node Type', field: 'node_type_display'},
  {name: 'hostname', label: 'Hostname', field: 'hostname', sortable: true},
  {name: 'username', label: 'Username', field: 'username', sortable: true},
]
```

As stated, the code works as expected and the application can clearly access the values it needs, but I'd like to resolve the warnings. What is wrong here, or what could be better?